# Legitimate detailed question was put on hold on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, bounties, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked a question on Stack Overflow: [CSS full-page-width horizontal menu and horizontal submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240844/css-horizontal-menu-and-horizontal-submen)

The question was answered by 3 people, and the answers were not complete. So I offered a bounty for it, and then it was put on hold. It was put on hold for the reason:

> [...] must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved

I explained the question very well, in a very detailed manner. I think it was put on hold for no apparent reason.

How can I protest this question from being put on hold, and remove the held status from the question?

### EDIT - NOTE:

**What's up with the negative votes! I was asking for clarification and I get negative votes???**

Comment: Did you read the rest of the description of the close reason? What else does it say?

Comment: This is the comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist" The link to the check list is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Do you think its possible that someone could read your Q as a detailed list of specifications requesting that someone write some code for you? As opposed to an attempted solution that didn't work about which you are asking for help?

Comment: I did not do a list of specs, I really am detailed oriented, and was trying to explain it as such. The real problem is I could not creat a CSS structure that allows what I am asking for, and hence the question.

Comment: But where is your attempted solution? Your question contains background and a list of requirements, like an assignment.

Comment: So show an attempt at such a CSS structure and ask about how to make it work. The community here has decided that it does not really want questions in the form "I'd like a solution that does X, Y and Z." and nothing else.

Comment: It is not an assignment. I am a web developer and use WordPress. I have over 15 years experience. My attempted solutions did not get near the answer. I know how to do the horizontal part, however I was having a problem with extending the background. My attempted solutions are incorrect, and hence I asked hte question.

Comment: All you needed to do was include your attempted solution, that's all. Just like it says in the close reason! :)

Comment: RE: Your edit: The title of this question pre-supposes that the question was "legitimate" and therefore erroneously put on hold. People who *disagree* with that assumption, and therefore think that the question was *correctly* put on hold, have likely downvoted this question. Downvotes are often used to signify disagreement. Contrary to your whine, you were *not* simply "asking for clarification", you were protesting the question being closed. You have every right to do what, but people also have every right to disagree.

Comment: Thanks for your nice language Cody Gary.

Comment: Good edit to the question, by the way. I'm happy to see the question was reopened.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Thanks for your feedback. I just got a bit unhappy first, to be honest, but then when having a discussion with you and others, I realized your points. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

I am the one who refunded the bounty and put the question on hold. I was responding to a flag with which I agreed.

Basically, your question amounted to a list of requirements, and not much else. Your sample code did not represent an effort you had tried and failed at, but seemingly just a starting point to tack the code you were requesting into.

I saw no evidence of attempts you had made there.

As a result, I refunded your bounty and put the question on hold.

Comment: As explained in the other comments. I never found a solution that extends the background to the edges. My attempted solutions cannot do any of that, so I asked the question. The problem it seams that there isn't enough emphasis on that fact.

Comment: @Greeso Ummm... no. The problem is what I have described above.

Comment: Anyway, will edit that either tomorrow or the day after. It is getting too late now to do any work. Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask you, there seems to be an answer that was written just before you put the question on hold (I just read it), and this answer works correctly. I would like to accept that answer and offer the gentleman the bounty. I am referring to the answer by GraphicO.

Comment: @Greeso You are welcome to do whatever you are capable of doing there. I think you can choose the answer as accepted, but you can't put a bounty on a question on hold, and it won't be reopened just to permit a bounty.

Comment: @Greeso You can accept the answer now, it doesn't make any difference that the question is on hold. As for the bounty: Edit your code (your attempted solution) in the question. Then flag it for mod attention and ask for it to be re-opened. A moderator will review your edits, and if they find them sufficient they will re-open the question. When that happens, set the bounty again and award it to whatever answer you wish.

Answer (score 7):

I reread the question several times, and while I found myself on the fence at first, I'm inclined to agree with the close.  Here's why:

- Your question does describe a relatively common question (that is, [tabbed navigation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/06/showcase-of-well-designed-tabbed-navigation/)).
- Your question only offers a small sample of HTML and CSS, which is *well* beneath the amount required to get the sub-navigation working properly (it's an unordered list, laid out vertically)
- You provide a laundry list of requirements.  **Huge** red flag there.
- You say you're open to solutions with jQuery, but a few quick searches indicate that there is indeed answers to the problem with jQuery.
- In that vein, there are also solutions with pure CSS as well.
- Lastly, there are solutions on this site that cover your question as well.

Comment: OK, it appears that I should reword the question. I need to emphasize on the fact that the background for the solution requested should extend to the edges of the brouser, not the content area (which is point 5 in my description). Therefore I will reword it to emphasize on that fact. That fact only, makes the question very hard to solve, and hence I asked the question.

Comment: I think you're missing the forest for the trees.  The hint is that this is a solved problem in jQuery.  Try working with that *first*, then ask a question when you're really stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I'm the one who flagged the question. I've been finding more than a few bounty questions lately that read more like:

"Will you code this for me for X amount of rep?"

Or

"Will you reverse engineer this for me for X amount of rep?"

In my frustration with this trend of using Stack Overflow as a code writing service I just started flagging these for moderator attention, sorry if I miss read the intent of your question, but it definitely looked like one.

If you can re-word it to meet the the standards laid out in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) I would encourage you to do so.

Comment: I am re-writing it now. But I was thinking I should delete the whole question and re-write a new one, due to the negative downvotes that it got! I personally do not really care about stakoverflow points whatsoever, all I care is using it as a resource. Stackoverflow points do not pay my bills, my code does. Apparently however, negative questions tend to be something that no one looks at. Cheers.